# How to add OR conjunction between field conditions in EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database, entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using OR with EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14499/using-or-with-entityfieldquery)

I have this code in my module:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'activity')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_file_blackwhite', 'fid', $fid)
    ->fieldCondition('field_file_color', 'fid', $fid);
$nodes = $query->execute();
```

It should retrieve nodes with a certain fid in either "field_file_blackwhite" OR "field_file_color". Actually it querys not with OR but with AND so no nodes are found.

How can I use "OR" conjunction between both "fieldCondition" conditions?
I have tried with delta value but no luck.