# or condtion in EntityFieldQuery

Tags: entities

I want use `or` in `EntityFieldQuery` query,
I search and found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14499/using-or-with-entityfieldquery) but I dont understand how can I implement this, please instead of refer to another link or article tell me how can I add `or` condition on `propertyCondtion`
my job dont handle with `IN` operation .

Comment: I think the answer on that thread is what you're looking for!!! May be you should add comments to that answer on asking clear implementation explanation.

Comment: @Mathankumar if you understand it why you dont put anwer with implementation ?

Comment: Show the query you're trying to generate and the EFQ query generation code as well.