# select nodes title start with charachter

Tags: entities, database

I want to have query with `EntityFieldQuery` that return me nodes with title start with `A` or `B` but has not obvious method to use or in property condition,
I dont want use `db_select` or `db_query`.
in [this link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3apropertyCondition/7) not comes `like` but it work ,but  If I want use `REGEX` operator it return me error.

```
  $query=new EntityFieldQuery();
        $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'product_display')
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$query->propertyCondition('title', '^(B|A)','REGEX');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because there's no `REGEX` operator in MySQL.

You probably meant [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), which does work in an `EntityFieldQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no database agnostic support for regex in EntityFieldQuery. The documentation in [EntityFieldQuery::propertyConditon](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3apropertyCondition/7) lists the available operators. As mentioned by Clive, this list is not complete. Apparently you can use any operator that is supported by your database backend.

As an alternative that should be supported across different database backends, you could build multiple queries using the `STARTS_WITH` operator and then merge the results.

Or you write a custom query using db_query. Or use db_select with [or-linked conditions](https://api.drupal.org/comment/51408#comment-51408).

Comment: I told in question ,I dont want use db_select or db_query, really is not clear  way to using or in EntityFieldQuery ??

Comment: No, you didn't write that in the question. I just told you, that what you want is not possible with EntityFieldQuery, at least not for propertyConditions.

Comment: @zhilevan You probably saw [this thread](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14499/using-or-with-entityfieldquery) already? It explains an alternative using tags.

Comment: @berliner I have one parameter in my codes  that I want use it in myCondition,how can I pass my parameter to addTag function ?

Comment: This isn't right actually, `EntityFieldQuery` transparently supports any valid MySQL operator

Comment: @Clive Can you point me somewhere with more information on that? Like how to use regexes with EntityFieldQuery?

Comment: @berliner Sure, for the OP's specific example, change the last line to `$query->propertyCondition('title', '^(B|A)','REGEXP'); `. Works perfectly. There's nothing specific for regexs as such - the operator is passed straight through from the PHP condition statement, so pretty much anything will work

Comment: @Clive Ah, right, then I got misleaded by the documention of [EntityFieldQuery::propertyCondition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3ApropertyCondition/7) which lists the available operators without mentioning that the possible values are not limited to the listed ones. But it probably breaks compatibility with other database backends?

Comment: @berliner Almost certainly, yes :) Yeah the documentation is a bit misleading, but maybe it's trying to be as neutral as possible, like you say, and not encourage people to write modules that will be incompatible with different back ends

Comment: @Clive ok, thanks for explaining, I have updated my answer to reflect this.