# Nested OR clause with EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database

I have a table products structure like this

```
product_id   product_name   product_created_date   product_expiry_date  availability  
----------   ------------   -------------------    -------------------  ------------
    1           x             12-NOV-13                14-JUN-14               No
    2           y             13-DEC-13                   null                Yes
    3           z             14-DEC-14                14-DEC-15              Yes
    1           p             12-NOV-13                14-JUN-14              Yes 
    ----        --             -----                     ----               ----
```

I need a query like :

```
select product_id from products where (product_expiry_date>='12-DEC-14' or product_expiry_date is null) and availability='Yes'
```

how to do this using EntityFieldQuery?

Comment: Is that a table used from an entity. If it is not an entity, you cannot use `EntityFieldQuery`.

Comment: Yes, this table is from entity and i am able to retrive them without null, but i need that null records as well

Comment: Please take a look to this post http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14499/using-or-with-entityfieldquery about using OR in EFQ. :-)

Comment: Its not possible. Check this post http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14499/using-or-with-entityfieldquery "It is not possible, if not subclassing EntityFieldQuery, and overriding some methods." "One way round it might be to add a tag to the query with with ->addTag(), then implement hook_query_TAG_alter() to change the internal structure of the query manually for queries containing that tag."

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a query like that once, here is how I achieve this with EFQ:

```
$matches = array();
yourmodule_mini_query('12-DEC-14', $matches);
yourmodule_mini_query('null', $matches);

function yourmodule_mini_query($value, &$matches) {
  $entityQuery = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query = $entityQuery->entityCondition('entity_type', 'product');
  $query->fieldCondition('product_expiry_date', 'value', $value, '=');
  $query->fieldCondition('availability', 'value', 'Yes', '=');
  $results = $query->execute();

  if(count($results)) {
    foreach ($results['product'] as $p) {
      // By using product_id as array key, you deal with the duplicates
      $matches[$p->product_id] = $p->product_id;
    }
  }
}
```

Where `$matches` contains an **array of product_id's** that are available and for which `product_expiry_date` is `null` **OR** `12-DEC-14`.

Hope it helped.

**EDIT:** As said in the comments below, the evaluation of the NULL value may require a second distinct query instead of calling twice the same function.

Comment: Isn't this second call to the mini query function going to query for fields with value as "null" string (I.e instead of an `IS NULL`, it queries `value='null'`.

Comment: Oh, actually, I haven't thought about that null value but indeed, it surely will. Maybe two distinct queries are inevitable here... Thanks for the tip :p