# How to use Entityfieldquery with two field conditions for the same field

Tags: database

I need to make a query where the same filed must have one value OR another. Basically:

```
->fieldCondition($field_example, 'tid', (array) $var1) ... OR
->fieldCondition($field_example, 'tid', (array) $var2)
```

Already saw some examples using TAG but I really don't understand how it's done.
In alternative, can I use dbquery? Or should I avoid it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `db_or()`, something like this:

```
$or = db_or()
  ->fieldCondition($field_example, 'tid', (array) $var1)
  ->fieldCondition($field_example, 'tid', (array) $var2);
$query->condition($or);
```

More info [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_or/7).

Comment: Thanks m1n0. I want to add that condition but I already have other in my query. `$query = new EntityFieldQuery(); $query ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')->entityCondition('bundle', 'content_x') ->propertyCondition('status', 1)->fieldOrderBy('field_date', 'value', 'DESC') ->fieldCondition('field_division', 'tid', (array) $division) ... The OR condition here... ... ->range(0, 5) ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); $result = $query->execute();` So, I need not just the OR but to have the code I already had and the OR.

Answer (score 1):

In EFQ, `db_or()` is not possible to add. So both the top answers are wrong!

By adding a TAG to the query and later altering it seems to be the best possible way. However I've found that using basic `db_select` instead of EFQ for those cases serves me good.

But who wants to add OR to EFQ: [Using OR with EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14499/using-or-with-entityfieldquery)